JS files Listed several times in Page Speed
My website has a few js files at the bottom. As you can see on the picture, some of them are listed several times as per the index page itself. Does it mean they're downloaded more than once?
Thanks


That measurement is about the time spent executing functions rather than the time spent downloading the scripts.  They have only been downloaded once, but will be called multiple times to generate your page.
It's basically a limited version of the performance tab in your dev tools.
It's usually worth clicking through to the read more documentation on PageSpeed Insights, as they are pretty good at explaining what all their measurements mean.
